# C++ How to get the right return from dll function call

Tags: c++, dll

I have atm this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //Define ScreenResolition
    int DesktopResolution[] = { GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) };
    cout << "DesktopResolution: <" << DesktopResolution[0] << ", " << DesktopResolution[1] << ">\n";    

    //Load DLL
    HINSTANCE IShndl = NULL;
    IShndl = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\Bilbao\\Desktop\\C++\\Hello World\\Project1\\Project1\\DLLS\\ImageSearch.dll");
    if (IShndl != NULL){
        cout << "ISHandle: " << IShndl << "\n";

        //DEFINE
        cout << "Define... \n";

        typedef int(__stdcall * FuncImageSearch)(int aLeft, int aTop, int aRight, int aBottom, string aImageFile);
        typedef int(__stdcall * FuncDLLTest)(int a);

        //Set ImageSearch
        cout << "Set ImageSearch... \n";
        FuncImageSearch ImageSearch;
        ImageSearch = NULL;

        //Set Test Function
        cout << "Set Test Function... \n";
        FuncDLLTest ISTest;
        ISTest = NULL;


        //Get ImageSearch
        cout << "GetProcAddress 'ImageSearch'... \n";       
        ImageSearch = (FuncImageSearch)GetProcAddress(IShndl, "ImageSearch");
        if (ImageSearch != NULL){
            cout << "ImageSearch: " << ImageSearch << "\n";         
            int answer  = ImageSearch(0, 0, DesktopResolution[0], DesktopResolution[1], "C:\\Users\\Bilbao\\Desktop\\C++\\Hello World\\Project1\\Project1\\DLLS\\test.bmp");            
            cout << "ImageSearch CALL return: Size " << sizeof(answer) << "\n";
            cout << "ImageSearch CALL: " << answer << "\n";
            if (answer == 1){
                cout << "Found Image: \n";
            }
            else{
                cout << "No ImageFound. \n";
            }
        }


        //Get Test Function
        cout << "GetProcAddress 'ImageTest'... \n";
        //ISTest = (FuncDLLTest)GetProcAddress(IShndl, "ImageTest");        
        ISTest = (FuncDLLTest)GetProcAddress(IShndl, "ImageTest");
        if (ISTest != NULL){
            cout << "ISTest: " << ISTest << "\n";
            int TestValue = 100; //1
            while(TestValue < 10){
                cout << "test: " << TestValue << "\n";
                int ISTestRestult = ISTest(TestValue);
                cout << "ISTEST CALL return: " << ISTestRestult  << "\n";               
                TestValue++;
            }
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is now, that I dont get the right return from `ImageSearch`.
The DLL-Return is this:

```
sprintf(answer,"1|%d|%d|%d|%d",locx,locy,image_width,image_height);
return answer;
```

Now I have no idea how to get it in an usable format. If I use int, I already got the first arg right(1 = image found, 0 = no image found) but I never get valid x/y coordinates back.
(The dll works, I used it in autoit.)

Does anyone have a idea? I am trying since hours and at the end of my (google-)knowledge

sincerly :)

Comment: let me guess:  `answer` is a local variable of your dll function ?

Comment: Yes, but via return it gets into the main call(i also can call it there result or whatever) The return works, but the type seems to be wrong/an array or so idk : /

Comment: If it's a local variable, it is detroyed immediately after the return.  Thus the containt can no longer be considered safe in main() !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that answer is local data AND an char array.  As it is an array it can't be returned by value.  Only a pointer to answer will be returned.  But as it's local data, it gets destroyed immediately after return.  So trying to acces it is undefined behaviour.

I propose you the following approach:

1) Define a structure which is shared between the dll and you application:

```
    struct MyData { 
        int x,y,width,height; 
    };
```

2) Change the signature of your dll function to return this structure by value:

```
   MyData ImageSearch(....) {
        MyData d; 
        ...
        //sprintf(answer,"1|%d|%d|%d|%d",locx,locy,image_width,image_height);
        d.x=locx; d.y=locy; ... 
        return  d;
   }
```

Alternatively, you could also call the function, using arguments for the expected result passed by referefence.  Then your function may return the result by writing directly into the variables passed by main.

Comment: Ty, i will try it it. I am pretty new to c++ and still reading a lot. Here is the dll code http://privatepaste.com/87b95dd01b# in case you wanan watch at it(its public, and working fine for autoit for what it was mainly made ;( )

Comment: Found out, that this helped to solve all problems: cout << "ImageSearch CALL: " << answer->c_str() << "\n\n";